# Could Charles Valentin Alkan play his own compositions?

Tags: piano, technique, composition, classical-music, romantic-period

Could *Charles Valentin Alkan* play his own compositions?
I'm very curious, since his compositions are extremely difficult, and I've only seen a few pianists who were able to play these compositions.

For example his *etude opus 39 no. 12*...

I find his etudes very interesting, however, I keep thinking about whether he was able to even play them himself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that he was. Liszt admired his technical abilities, which he considered to be on a par with his own. [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles-Valentin_Alkan) a bio.